# Create a floating sidebar in shiny dashboard

Tags: css, r, twitter-bootstrap-3, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using the latest version of shiny dashboard and leaflet to create a shiny App (See my minimum example below). This Shiny app is working very well in my computer. However, the leaflet map is pushing into right side in my mobile as expected (See this figure).

[image]

So, my question is it is possible to create a floating sidebar which will float on the leaflet map.

PS: Here is an example floating sidebar (at the right-top corner. http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/sA6H7U/).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Leaflet test')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
        div.outer {
             height: calc(100vh - 80px);
             padding: 0;
             margin: 0;
             min-height: 500px
        }
    ")))
    , tags$div(
        class = 'outer',
        leafletOutput('map', width = '100%', height = '100%')) 
)



ui <- dashboardPage(
    header, sidebar, body
    , title = 'Leaftlet test'
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({

        leaflet() %>% 
            addTiles()
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I can't see the floating sidebar in your linked example.

Comment: At the right-top corner.

Comment: I cant see it either